# How and where to create aidl file in eclipse using android

Tags: android

I am trying to using remote service in android.can anybody tell how and where to create aidl file in eclipse in android?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right click the Package name -> New -> File

Provide a filename with the .aidl extension, such as MyServiceInterface.aidl

Answer (score 2):

You have lot of examples available for this topic.

1. You can refer to API Demos example where in they have implemented a Remote service.
2. Refer this [link](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/09/android-developer-tutorial-part-9.html).

Answer (score 2):

According to the  follow  setps:

1. File -> New -> File.
2. create file with .aidl extension, such as IRemoteService.aidl.
3. Project -> Build Automatically.
4. you will find IRemoteService.java under gen folder.